# Statistical analysis of academic grades

Tags: ordinal-data, wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test, fishers-exact-test

Let's say I have 2 sets of grades from students. Maybe I'm looking at gender differences or some such but the disaggregating factor could be continuous or multinomial.

Group A: 3 D's, 5 C's, 13 B's and 2 A's.
Group B: 2 D's, 3 C's, 7 B's and 11 A's.

How do I perform a statistical analysis to determine whether the grades of B are significantly better than those of group A?

Would it just be a case of multiple chi-squared or Fisher tests, pivoting on grade X or better? Is there a Mann-Whitney-U equivalent that I could use?

It would be preferable that I could also include confounding variables. Like whether students had any additional tutoring on the side. But it's not necessary.

Comment: Note that any standard analysis will treat the students as independent, which in many real situations (for example if they study together) is inappropriate. In a simple two groups setup this can not even be detected from the data, as any difference you see could be explained by either difference in distributions or dependence (or a mix of both). So whetever you do will rely on the students behaving like an independent random sample from the population you wish to generalise to.

Comment: @ChristianHennig Do you mean because student m is more likely to get an A because student n gets an A, kind of thing?

Comment: That's a possibility, for example if they learn together. In general one can't know for sure how dependence plays out, but teachers know there's interaction and that can often make a difference. (Of course only if there is in fact interaction in case of your sample.)

Answer (score 3):

One solution is to convert grades to GPA and then do a t-test or U test.  A = 4, B = 3. C = 2. D = 1. F = 0 is the usual way to do this. Or, if you have covariates, you could use some form regression.

If you want to keep the grades ordinal, then you could do a test that accounts for that, like Jonckheere-Terpstra, or, with covariates, you could use ordinal logistic regression.

Comment: Both look like excellent suggestions. Many thanks.

Comment: Wilcoxon/Mann-Whitney (which I guess is what you call U) with correction for ties keeps grades ordinal as well, i.e., it doesn't use information other than the order.

Comment: That said I wouldn't worry too much about a t-test here (violations of distributional assumptions will normally be harmless but see my comment under the question); in a regression setup it's a different matter because of floor and ceiling effects.

Comment: The initial paragraph is a poor recommendation due to its statistically unsupported assumption that these grades ought to be coded numerically using the values given.  Simple, better methods abound.  What is needed here is a more thoughtful analysis of how the differences among the grades should be quantified.